# Setting the div as the root element in Intersection Observer API

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I trying  set the div as the root element in observer . When targetBox  has intersection  with rootBox, it must
send  message to console, but it doesn't work. If as root set null observer work correctly

```js
const rootBox = document.getElementById("rootBox");
const targetBox = document.querySelector('.targetBox');

const obsCallback = function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(enrty => console.log('obs works'));
}
const obsOptions = {
  root: rootBox,
  threshold: [0, 0.5],
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(obsCallback, obsOptions);
observer.observe(targetBox);
```

```css
header {
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.targetBox {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(86, 86, 250);
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.rootBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 3, 3);
  background-color: rgb(197, 95, 248);
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="rootBox" id="rootBox"></div>
  <div class="targetBox" id="targetBox"></div>
</header>
```

Example

[image]

I tried change position to fixed but in doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targets must be descendants of `root`

```
<header id="header">
  <div class="rootBox" id="rootBox">
    <div class="targetBox" id="targetBox"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Here is your example, just with an anonymous function and a CSS animation that moves the targetBox up and down for the visualisation of the console calls, ( I imagine it will be useful for everyone )

```js
const rootBox = document.getElementById('rootBox');
const targetBox = document.querySelector('.targetBox');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer)
{
 entries.forEach(entry => {
    
 const idname = entry.target.id; // target = html element
 const inout = (entry.isIntersecting)? '' : 'not';
 const ratio = (entry.intersectionRatio).toFixed(5);
    
 console.log('Fn called due threshold', ratio , 'with', idname , '( '+ inout +' intersecting)');

   });
   
},{
  root: rootBox,
  threshold: [0, 0.5],
});


observer.observe(targetBox);
```

```css
header {
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.targetBox {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(86, 86, 250);
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top:122px;
  
  animation: movingTopToBottom 20s linear infinite;
}

.rootBox {
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 3, 3);
  background-color: rgb(197, 95, 248);
}

@keyframes movingTopToBottom {
  0% {
    top: -70px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 120px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="rootBox" id="rootBox">
    <div class="targetBox" id="targetBox"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```